# Using Graph to get email on a Government cloud

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I have been tasked with creating a C# daemon that is supposed to connect government cloud to a specific user's email, pull said email and parse out specific emails with attachments that represent registration objects. This should be a simple task. I remember doing this exact same task in the days of CDO, outlook web access and exchange web services back in the ancient times.

I have a second second section that connects to a commercial cloud and by and large that appears to be working (except the main property that I need to access is behind Microsoft's paywall). It's the government cloud part I am having trouble with. Unfortunately almost every tutorial or guide I have found has been for commercial tenants and the remainder simply did not work. As a result I am getting a bit aggravated. My test harness app has so many packages in it now that I wonder if there are any left I don't have referenced.

I have the tenant_id, I have the client_id, I have the client_secret. I also have an array of scopes (though there is only one at the moment), a redirect_uri and an authority_uri. I have the email itself, and a password for it as well. My admin contact assures me that all necessary permissions have been assigned. But every tutorial I have tried has offered one error or another which has been leading me around in circles in google.

Has anyone tried to do this that knows of a tutorial for a government tenant that will allow me to access a specific email inbox thought graph or some other technology?

thanks in advance,
EK

Comment: I would suggest that you are probably asking the wrong question. [so] collectively has a great deal of knowledge among it's contributors and you will likely be better off asking about specific errors backed by a representative example of your code. As it stands this question is really asking for another off site resource which is off-topic here.

Comment: unfortunately I am at the point where I'm not sure what question to ask to get me back on track.

For example, the code I have for the commercial tenant connection works overall fine.  I can't get to the signInActivity property that I need but that appears to be because of the license model they're using (it's not a premium license) and there doesn't seem to be a way around it.

but when I use the exact same code to try to access the government tenant it fails with:

Comment: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance. 

or this:

AADSTS900382 confidential client is not supported in cross cloud request using the government tenant credentials.

or a few others that have happened. I've been trying and failing to find a path to get into the inbox I need through graph which is making me wonder if Graph is not the solution i need.